# How to link an object to an HTTP request within a Webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm rather new to android development and I can't find answers, nor solutions, to the question above.

Here's my case: I'm developing an android webapp. This webapp includes a webview and some functionalities like Qr code reading. What I need to do is calling an API and giving to this API what is inside the Qr code.
I can navigate well through the webView and my Qr reading function works fine.

To sum up, I get a URI after reading a Qr Code and I need to attach this url to my HTTP request to an API.

So, is it possible to add some kind of parameters to the function **webView.loadUrl(url)** so it calls the url while delivering the url I got from the Qr code?

Sorry if i'm not clear. That's my first post on StackOverflow. Do not hesitate to give me advices on how to write good posts.
Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well if i get your problem i suggest you to use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, in this case you will be able to add any params to the url

Comment: So if I understand, @Max Aves, I should call the API within the webview and then use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to add the URL, as a parameter, needed by the API?

Comment: well as long as qr functionality will get triggered and you will have the param, u can override url